# Processing a local file from a server

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is currently working locally that I'd like to put on a server.

Currently, the user choose a .txt file, the PHP script works on it and outputs a new file based on what it read in the file.
The problem is that I can only select files in the folder with the script, and not elsewhere.
I use a  to get the file name, but it only gives out the name of the file, and not it's absolute path.

From what I've read, I think that I need to upload the file to the server, process it with the script and then give it back to the user.
I'm not sure this is the correct method though.

Also, while I have found plenty of informations on uploading files to the server, I don't know how to put the new file created by the script in the folder where the original file is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to give the file back to the client, as a downloadable file. You can "write" it to the user by setting some headers. Take a look:

```
<?php
$file = 'random_text_file.txt';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

That will prompt a download of the file to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read or write files directly on the client's machine. The client will need to upload the file by selecting it in the browser, the server receives the data, processes the data and returns data. This returned data can be presented in the form of a file download by setting the appropriate HTTP headers. The client will have to acknowledge the file download and save it somewhere of his choosing.

Your server has no business knowing anything about files or folders on the client's machine. It can only communicate with it over the HTTP protocol and send and receive *data*.